# Ubuntu One says it's always synchronizing

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I opened the Ubuntu Once Preference box to see if everything was "up to date" come to find that it's still "Synchronizing" after leaving the window open for three hours.

[image]

When I execute `u1sdtool --status`

```
State: STANDOFF
    connection: With User With Network
    description: waiting for connection to end
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: IDLE
```

Is this it's idle text - or is it trying really, really hard to get something synchronized?

Comment: What is the output of `u1sdtool --status`?

Comment: `is_online : False` that means ubuntu one isn't really connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Standoff" means the connection is half-dead. After a short delay you should see syncdaemon trying to reconnect; as this seems to not be the case, please consider restarting syncdaemon (`u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c`). If the problem persists, please enable debug and file a bug.

Comment: Restarting the tool as you mentioned worked. Wireless in this part of my place isn't the most...reliable. Thank you!

Comment: @Chipaca - Is there a way to do that in Windows?

Comment: @Enigma quit U1 from the system tray, restart it from the menu.

Comment: @Chipaca - I had to uninstall, remove all leftover data and then re-install for it to connect successfully.

Comment: @Enigma ouch. If that ever happens again please contact support, so we can get the log files and fix whatever the root issue was.